# If $a$ and $b$ are nonzero integers such that each is a divisor of the other, show that $a = ± b$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra

I tried many approaches to this problem. I believe that if I did $b|a=m$ and $a|b=n$ and set $m=n$, then $a$ and $b$ would be equal. Is that how it should be done? If not, please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $b|a = m$ is nonsensical. $b|a$ simply means that $b$ is a divisor of $a$, so it cannot be equated to anything. What you can do:

$a|b$ so there exists some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $an = b$.

$b|a$ so there exists some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $bm = a$

So we get $bmn=b$ meaning that $b = 0$ or $mn = 1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Suppose $mn=1$, then $b=b$. Then if I did the same thing with $amn=a$ and $a=0$ or $mn=1$. Then $a=a$. But how would I show that $a=b$?

Comment: Well, it's clear from the very beginning that $a=a$ and $b=b$, so going that direction won't get very far. Rather, since $mn=1$ what can you say about $m$ and $n$ themselves?

Comment: I would believe $m$ and $n$ are multiplicative inverses of each other.

Comment: Correct, but since $m$ and $n$ are integers there are only two possibilities. Namely, either $n=m=1$ or $n=m=-1$.

Comment: Oh yeah since $m,n ∈ Z$ Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. And in case it isn't obvious by now, for the other case where $b=0$ we have that $a=0$ and so clearly $a = \pm b$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively $\ a\mid b\,\Rightarrow\, |a| \le |b|,\,$ so $\,|b| \le |a|$ by symmetry, so $|b| = |a|$